# How Often Do you Back Up your Subversion Repository?

Tags: svn, backup, tortoisesvn

I wanted to know the frequency at which different shops are backing up their repositories.  I have heard some even go to the extent of every 5 minutes to prevent from having to worry about after a restore, going through everyone's local Projects to find and merge in any uncommitted changes that are missing after a restore.

- How big is your shop (# developers)
- How often is the repo backed up?

Comment: there are really 3 questions here, "how often do you" and "how often should you" "how often do you say you do when people ask"

Comment: What should factor in is how important what you're doing is.

Answer (score 3):

Make daily backups - put them on another partition, machine, physical site - and purge old backups logarithmically (this is an example, adapt it to your context):

- keep all snapshots from today and yesterday
- keep one snapshot for the last week and one for two weeks ago
- keep one snapshot per month for all previous month of this year
- keep one snapshot per year for all previous years

Or follow the Dilbert approach:

[image: OUr Disaster Recovery Plan Goes Something Like This]
<sub>(source: [ntpro.nl](http://www.ntpro.nl/blog/uploads/Dilbert.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It's an version-control repository, it already has the history inside. Why save ancient versions of it? :)

Answer (score 3):

When I managed the svnserver for a team of 15 or so developers:

1. Sync to mirror server on each commit
2. Mirror server dumps each revision on commit
3. Nightly incremental backups on main server
4. Weekly bulk backups on main server, keeping 2 weeks history

Comment: I'm glad there others that like to have every commit trigger the backup.  Some people don't realize it, but you can do an incremental dump of the revision just committed in a subversion post-commit hook, and have that same hook push to a remote backup system.

Comment: (+1) for a nice comment .. :)

Answer (score 2):

- 4 developpers
- We back up one time per day (at 3AM)

Answer (score 2):

- doing a backup is good
- testing that the backup actually works is better

So don't forget to install the backed up copy once in a while onto a throwaway Subversion server, just to make sure that everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

- 1-2 developers
- Once a day at around midnight

Answer (score 1):

When considering how often or whether to back up. Think about how much a day/week's work is worth to you. In any professional environment the cost of a couple of developer days probably equals the cost of a backup server and the few minutes to set up a cron job to run `svnadmin dump`. At a minimum you should be backing up every day unless your data (or time) is worth nothing to you.

The ideal is to have a complete hot mirror of your repository that can also help to reduce load on an individual server. If you are considering setting up a backup process for Subversion (or CVS), have  look at [WANdisco](http://www.wandisco.com/). They provide various clustering/mirroring solutions that allow you to scale your repository and transparently recover from errors.

> Subversion High Availability provides continuous hot backup, while making failover and disaster recovery automatic and transparent for both developers and administrators.

[image: high availability screenshot]
<sub>(source: [wandisco.com](http://www.wandisco.com/images/4/ha_iso.gif))</sub>

If you have multiple sites or a large site, you could also consider their clustering or multi-site systems for a shared-nothing load balanced Subversion cluster.

[image: clustering screen shot]
<sub>(source: [wandisco.com](http://www.wandisco.com/images/4/c_iso.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

- I am the only developer.
- I back it up often. I use my mozy account.

Answer (score 0):

- 3-4 developers
- Back up the repository (svnadmin dump) manually once a month or so. The server where the repository resides is backed up separately, and if the repository itself becomes corrupted, we still have a working copy in 3-4 workstations.

Well, now that I think about it, there's really no reason that the repository couldn't be backed up more often, and automatically. And maybe it should.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SVN on personal / consulting projects where I am the only developer.

I back it up at the end of every day of development to a flash drive.

At the office where we have 3-5 developers but DON'T USE SVN we are backing up the central repository once a night.

Answer (score 0):

We're 3 developers and I'm doing a backup every night.

But that really depends of the server where you've your svn installed. Maybe it's doing shadow copies, it's a redundant server, .... That also depends of the amount of developers, how big is the project.

I don't think there's a single valid answer.

Comment: no, but it's good to know, that's all I'm posting this for...people's experiences.  I'm looking to back up every 5 minutes which is what another gentleman does to prevent any issue for a team with having to worry about getting their local updates into an older restore.

Answer (score 0):

Most people adopt a fairly relaxed attitude to backups, with a "once in a blue moon policy".

Until that day.

You know the one.

After that day, you get pretty good at it. You figure you never want to lose more than a days work, and you make damned sure that's what happens! In answer the question, we perform a daily rsync of our subversion repository and trac database to an offsite location.

Comment: that day was today.  I wish I had backed them up every 5 minutes yes, that often!  Because you have to merge local changes after.  Just restoring a repository doesn't mean you're done.  That's the easy part.  You must go through every developer's box, every project, folder, and get their updates back into the restored older repository like I had to.  If I basically had close to up to the minute restores, most likely there would be very few instances if any where a developer checked in code in the past 5 minutes..and restoring would be like nothing ever happened - repo versions would match

Comment: Heh, that you, coffeeaddict? ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440950/restoring-a-subversion-repository-and-getting-it-back-up-to-date-with-everyones

Answer (score 0):

Same as other we backup at 4:30 everyday. However, there is one important point, never place your backup server in same room. Also move your backup DVD's to another location from time to time. In an event of catastrophe you will not loose everything.

Answer (score 0):

- 2 developers
- We back up daily to a different drive on a different machine
- We back up monthly off site

Answer (score 0):

1 developer. I back it up every night at 3am.

I use winzip to zip the entire repository and upload it to a remote ftp, so the backup I have is in a different physical location to prevent from data loss due to theft or fire.

I don't keep old backups since the svn repository itself contains all history.

I simply use winzip's internal scheduling for automatic zipping and ftp-uploading. Simple and effective

Comment: How do you prevent simultaneous access of the SVN repos?  You may want to copy it first with svnadmin to avoid the chance of corrupting the repository and then overwriting your previous backup.

Comment: Since I'm the only developer on the project, and I normally don't work at 3am, it's not a problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I rarely backup my personal svn repository - I've been doing it manually about once a month since pre 1.4 days, and should really set up **`svnsync`** some time.  `svnsync` is great.  On  the other hand, for a personal repository, a backup is slightly less crucial to me; I'd lose some history, but the important bits are in checkouts on several remote workstations which are themselves backed up; actual content wouldn't be lost.

At work, someone else manages the backup, and it's probably not a good thing that I don't have a clue as to the set up.

Seriously though, nowadays, with svnsync, a reasonable backup is trivial to set up.  Sure, it won't include your commit hooks, and that's not good - but a trivial remote backup of all content is certainly a good thing.  And as for commit hooks, you'll just need to back those up seperately.  Since they're liable to change almost never, this is doable.  With svnsync, you really can set the mirror to backup every 5 minutes - and best of all, the syncing mirror is itself a fully valid svn repository, which, if you plan it, can be used as a replacement svn server almost instantly should the primary server go down (you'd need to sort out things like access control, and replace svnsyncs hooks with your normal set, and you'd want to give the new server the same DNS name as the old server for a truly seemless transition).

Answer (score 0):

Daily. Doesn't matter how many peoplle. Just run the backup as a cron job.

(At home I do a weekly backups)